# NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I get this error just after updating Expo and Expo-Cli:

```
Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

To fix this issue try these steps:

  • Run `react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage` in the project root.

  • Rebuild and restart the app.

  • Run the packager with `--reset-cache` flag.

  • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app.

  • If this happens while testing with Jest, check out docs how to integrate AsyncStorage with it: https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest

If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage/issues
```

It started when I learnt that AsyncStorage is depreciated from react-native-community, so i installed `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and manually changed all the import statement but its still not working.

Plus I'm not sure how to `Run` react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage `in the project root.`